# nameref fails when chapter title has macro

Tags: hyperref, chapters

I'm trying to use `\nameref` for chapters. It works fine as long as the `\chapter` command has no macros as argument. If the `\chapter` command takes a macro as argument, `\nameref` always prints the last chapter name. `\autoref` works fine though. A MWE is here.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=Blue
}

\pgfkeys{%
  /chapter/.is family,%
  /chapter,%
  title/.initial = {},%
  label/.initial = {},%
}

\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{/chapter, #1, title/.get = \theChapterTitle, label/.get = \theChapterLabel}%
  \chapter{\theChapterTitle}\label{\theChapterLabel}%
}

\newcommand{\ChapRef}[1]{%
  \autoref{#1} {\textemdash} \nameref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
%
\Chapter{label=chapter-one, title=Chapter One}
%
\Chapter{label=chapter-two, title=Chapter Two}
%
\Chapter{label=chapter-three, title=Chapter Three}
%

\ChapRef{chapter-one}

\ChapRef{chapter-two}

\ChapRef{chapter-three}

\end{document}
```

Further to my comment I'm attaching a MWE of what I mean about \chapter command taking multiple arguments.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
}

\pgfkeys{%
  /chap/.is family,%
  /chap,%
  label/.initial = {},%
  one/.initial = {},%
  two/.initial = {},%
}

\let\ea=\expandafter

\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{/chap, #1, one/.get=\First, two/.get=\Second, label/.get=\thechaplabel}%
  \ea\chapter{\ea\ea\ea\First\,\ea\textemdash\,\ea\Second}\label{\thechaplabel}
}

\newcommand{\ChapRef}[1]{%
  \autoref{#1} - \nameref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\Chapter{one=ABC, two=abc, label={abc-abc}}
\Chapter{one=PQR, two=pqr, label={pqr-pqr}}
\Chapter{one=XYZ, two=xyz, label={xyz-xyz}}

\chapter{New Chapter}
\ChapRef{abc-abc}

\ChapRef{pqr-pqr}

\ChapRef{xyz-xyz}

\end{document}
```

the `\nameref` always displays the latest chapter name whereas the `\autoref` displays the correct chapter number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `\Chapter` macro stores `\ChapterTitle` in the name, not the name itself.

Just be sure to expand `\ChapterTitle` before `\chapter` looks at it:

```
\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{/chapter, #1, title/.get = \theChapterTitle, label/.get = \theChapterLabel}%
  \expandafter\chapter\expandafter{\theChapterTitle}\label{\theChapterLabel}%
}
```

This is not necessary with `\label`, because this command expands its argument, which must eventually reduce to a string.

---

I'm not sure the syntax you're using is easier to manage than the simpler

```
\chapter{Chapter One}\label{chapter-one}
```

---

For the more complex situation in which more keys are used, here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
}

\pgfkeys{%
  /chap/.is family,%
  /chap,%
  label/.initial = {},%
  one/.initial = {},%
  two/.initial = {},%
}

% \expandonce is provided by etoolbox
\providecommand{\expandonce}{\unexpanded\expandafter}
% hyperref doesn't like \, in bookmarks
\newcommand{\titleemdash}{%
  \texorpdfstring{\,\textemdash\,}{\textemdash}%
}

\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{/chap, 
    #1,
    one/.get=\First,
    two/.get=\Second,
    label/.get=\thechaplabel
  }%
  % use the (top level) value of \First and \Second
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\chapter{%
      \expandonce{\First}%
      \noexpand\titleemdash
      \expandonce{\Second}}}\x
  \label{\thechaplabel}
}

\newcommand{\ChapRef}[1]{%
  \autoref{#1} - \nameref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\Chapter{one=ABC, two=abc, label={abc-abc}}
\Chapter{one=PQR, two=pqr, label={pqr-pqr}}
\Chapter{one=XYZ, two=xyz, label={xyz-xyz}}

\chapter{New Chapter}
\ChapRef{abc-abc}

\ChapRef{pqr-pqr}

\ChapRef{xyz-xyz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: as per the use of `pgfkeys` for this in the OP's code, _to somebody with a hammer, everything looks like a nail_  :)

Comment: @jfbu Maybe some other keys are defined and the example has been reduced to the minimum showing the issue.

Comment: The actual code was even more complicated. I've reduced it to a Minimum to reproduce the issue.

Comment: My actual `\Chapter` command takes two arguments and assembles them to create `\chapter` command. I'm going to accept the answer. I'm struggling to find out how to use `\expandafter` in case of multiple arguments.

Comment: @Surya If you eventually do `\chapter[...]{...}` something more must be done; but without seeing the actual code, not much can be said.

Comment: Added new piece of code of the problem I'm facing.